# Обьясните пожалуйста часть кода

Tags: python

```
chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
check_string = "i am checking this string to see how many times each character appears"///
count = {}
for s in check_string:
  if s in count:
    count[s] += 1///эту часть
  else:
    count[s] = 1

for key in count:
  if count[key] > 1:
    print key, count[key]///и эту
```

Comment: `count[s] += 1` Прибавит значение правого операнда к левому и присвоит эту сумму левому операнду или так `count[s] = count[s] + 1`

Comment: Вы знаете, что такое словарь, и ключ и значение в нём?

Answer (score 0):

код, подсчитывающий сколько раз в тексте встречается та или иная буква и выводящая статистику, если буква встречается более 1 раза:

```
chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
check_string = "i am checking this string to see how many times each character appears"
count = {} # словарь в котором каждому ключу (букве) будет поставлено в соответствие кол-во попаданий
for s in check_string: # перебираем побуквенно строку
  if s in count: # если буква есть в словаре букв,
    count[s] += 1 # увеличиваем на 1 счетчик этой буквы (в словаре букв)
  else:
    count[s] = 1 # если буквы нет в словаре - добавляем запись в словарь

for key in count: # перебираем словарь букв по ключам (буквам из словаря)
  if count[key] > 1: # если счетчик больше 1
    print key, count[key] # выводим букву и сколько раз она встречалась в строке
```

только надо было бы писать так

```
print(key, count[key])
```

а не так

```
print key, count[key]
```

Вообще код можно сделать чуть-чуть покороче:

```
check_string = "i am checking this string to see how many times each character appears"
count = {}

for s in check_string:
    count[s] = count.get(s, 0) + 1

for key in count:
    if count[key] > 1:
        print(key, count[key])
```

или так:

```
for s in check_string:
    count[s] = count.get(s, 0) + 1

[print(key, count[key]) for key in count if count[key] > 1]
```

а можно даже так сделать:

```
check_string = "i am checking this string to see how many times each character appears"

for s in set(check_string):
    if check_string.count(s) > 1:
        print(s, check_string.count(s))
```

и ее однострочный вариант:

```
[print(s, check_string.count(s)) for s in set(check_string) if check_string.count(s) > 1]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!